# Inject Directive into Controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript

SOLVED:

I was using the wrong approach. Now I have defined a $watch in the link function of the directive, that calls the open() method on the controller of the directive.

Orginial Question:

I'm currently working on an Angular App developed with Typescript. Now I have to following problem, I have an Directive that contains an KendoUI Window as an Popup Window. This window in the directive should be opened from the controller of the main form.

Controller:

```
module CLogic.pps
{
'use strict';
export class produktionsAuftragDetailController
{
    ...
    static $inject = [
        '$scope',
        ...
        //'stListLoeschenWindow'
        ,'stListLoeschenFactory'
        ];      
    constructor(
        private $scope: any,
        ...
        //, private stListLoeschenWindow: CLogic.pps.directives.stListLoeschenDirective
        , private stListLoeschenFactory: CLogic.pps.directives.stListLoeschenDirective
        )
    {

   // Switch Form to Edit Mode
    aendern(stlD: CLogic.pps.directives.stListLoeschenController)
    {
    // Call the open method of the controller of the directive here
        stListLoeschenFactory.controller.open(1234);
    }
    ...
    }
}    
angular
    .module('CLogic.pps')
    .controller('CLogic.pps.produktionsAuftragDetailController',produktionsAuftragDetailController);
}
```

Directive:

```
module CLogic.pps.directives
{
'use strict';
export class stListLoeschenController
{
    public StListLoeschenWindow: kendo.ui.Window;

    private StListKey: number;public Fixieren: boolean;public Prodinfo: boolean;

    static $inject =
    [
        'CLogic.pps.services.ppsDataService','$log','hotkeys'
    ];
    constructor
        (public dataService: CLogic.pps.ppsDataService, private $log: ng.ILogService, public hotkeys: ng.hotkeys.HotkeysProvider
        )
    {
        this.Fixieren = false;
        this.Prodinfo = false;
    }
    // This is the method that should be called from the main Controller       
    open(index: number)
    {
        this.StListKey = index;
        this.StListLoeschenWindow.open();
        this.StListLoeschenWindow.center();
    }
}

export class stListLoeschenDirective implements ng.IDirective
{
    restrict = 'AE';
    templateUrl = 'CLogic/pps/detail/StListDeleteBestWindow.directive.html';
    controller = CLogic.pps.directives.stListLoeschenController;
    controllerAs = 'stListLoeschen';

    constructor(private ppsDataService: CLogic.pps.ppsDataService, $log: ng.ILogService, hotkeys: ng.hotkeys.Hotkey){}

    link: ng.IDirectiveLinkFn = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: ng.IAttributes)=>{ };

    static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory 
    {  
        var directive: ng.IDirectiveFactory = (ppsDataService, $log, hotkeys) => new stListLoeschenDirective(ppsDataService, $log, hotkeys);
        directive.$inject = ['CLogic.pps.services.ppsDataService', '$log', 'hotkeys'];
        return directive;
    }
}
angular
    .module('CLogic.pps.directives', [])
    .directive('stListLoeschenWindow', stListLoeschenDirective.factory())
    .factory('stListLoeschenFactory', stListLoeschenDirective.factory());
}
```

When I inject the factory the code works instead of the fact that I can get no reference to the controller of the directive (in the aendern method of the main controller). And when I try to inject the directive itself into the main controller I get an injector error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   stListLoeschenDirectiveProvider <- stListLoeschenDirective <-
>   CLogic.pps.produktionsAuftragDetailController
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/unpr?p0=stListLoeschenDirectiveProvider%20%3C-tListLoeschenDirective%20%3C-%20CLogic.pps.produktionsAuftragDetailController
>       at https://localhost:44302/Scripts/angular.js:68:12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shown in the question is clear:

> when angular tries to instantiate `CLogic.pps.produktionsAuftragDetailController` and therefore inject its dependency `static $inject = [ 'CLogic.pps.services.ppsDataService'` ... that **service** cannot be found

It seems, that you did not configured your factory properly.

The code above is **configuring it the same way** as is configured directive. And that could be the issue:

```
angular
    .module('CLogic.pps.directives', [])
    .directive('stListLoeschenWindow', stListLoeschenDirective.factory())
    // factory should be different then directive
    .factory('stListLoeschenFactory' , stListLoeschenDirective.factory());
```

Comment: As well when I comment out the ..factory('stListLoeschenFactory', stListLoeschenDirective.factory()); line and inject the following in the main controller, the error is the same:

static $inject = [
            '$scope',
           ...
            , 'stListLoeschenDirective'
            ];

constructor(
            private $scope: any,
           ...
            , private stListLoeschenDirective: CLogic.pps.directives.stListLoeschenDirective
            )

Comment: If you comment out.. .then the error cannot disappear, because it stil be UNKNOWN provider. So you have to define some... BUT ... you can never pass directive to controller! Never. The concept you've used is wrong. Think about it differently. There is a controller for Directive. There is another controller (other directive or view). They could be provided with some Factory/Service.. to change data. But Controller never ever can get Directive as dependency..

Comment: I only meant that I commented the "wrong" line, containing the .factory statement, out. 

If this is the wrong approach, how can I call the open() method in the controller of the directive from outside? I think an service or factory is not able to do this?

Comment: No, it is not able. But you can use it as **a way how to share data**. So one controller can $watch some Service property (passed as dependency) and do OPEN action, while other controller is just changing that property... If you would try to read more about how to communicate among directives.. you should see that it is the usuall and common way. hope it helps a bit - read this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: That is really great to see. Enjoy angular with Typescript ;)